# Error while installing rdiscount?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, redmine

I am trying to setuip redmine for which I have to install a lot of 'gems'. Well I have no knowledge of ruby on rails or gems or bundler. In the redmine installation doc they have ,mentioned that I use

```
bundle install --without development test
```

to install needed gems. I ran into some problems while installing json  due to which I had to install development kit. Now after installing the development kit and adding it to the environment variable (I am trying to install it on windows server ) I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694997/gem-install-json-v-1-7-3-gives-please-update-your-path-to-include-build-tools) . It says that after installing development kit I need to execute the following commands

```
Unzip the zip

open command-line and go to unzipperd folder

ruby dk.rb init

ruby dk.rb install

gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby
```

However while installing rdiscount I am getting the following error

[image]

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: I would suggest to move to Linux Environment. Windows is never recommended for Rails. :)

Comment: I am supposed to install redmine in a windows server hence I dont have that option until and unless I install virtual box !

Answer (score 0):

`rdiscount` is broken for windows. Check this issue: https://github.com/davidfstr/rdiscount/issues/74

> On win7 32bit using either mingw gcc 4.6.2 or mingw-w64 gcc 4.7.2 I
>   get gem build failures due to the use of the DWORD macro.
>
> The DWORD, WORD, and BYTE macros are known windows data types. Their
>   unfortunate re-use in discount/rdiscount causes problems with the
>   mingw/mingw-w64 headers as in the following failure:

Also refer to this SO for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15246336/3035830